# Linearized PDF in iOS Quartz 2D?

Tags: ios, pdf

I have developed a PDF Viewer by CGPDF*** methods.
It's annoyed with waiting a large PDF downloading, thus using a streaming PDF should be a good idea.

Is it possible to implement "Linearized PDF"(Fast Web View) by Quartz 2D in iOS?
 I can't find any example code or documents. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of PSPDFKit (a commercial iOS PDF SDK), and believe me, I also spent quite some time researching this topic. I don't think there's a way unless you use some 3rd party rendering framework like [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/). (But they are *really* expensive)

CGPDFDocument as it is now (iOS6) expects the trailer at the bottom and will fail on incomplete documents.

Comment: Sorry, typo(pressing the enter and sent the last comment)
First of all, thanks for your response.
Indeed, CGPDFDocument requires the trailer if loading PDF document and MuPDF can't achieve the requirement of this issue.
We create another mechanism to complete "PDF Streaming", parsing PDF's  architecture by MuPDF and rendering by CGPDFDocument.
Of course, we need to download version, header, trailer, xref table...and so on, before fetching objs in each page. It works. :-)